# How to create a lambda function to return next cell value?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

For example :

| Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- |
| 48 | 21 |
| 156 | 45 |
| 61 | 54 |
| 12 | 79 |
| 64 | 45 |

the excepted output is the followwing :

| Val1 | Val2 | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | 21 | 45 |
| 156 | 45 | 54 |
| 61 | 54 | 79 |
| 12 | 79 | 45 |
| 64 | 45 |  |

What I did try is the following but it does not work and I am not sure if it is possible to do with `lambda`.
)
)

```
DF["Output"] = DF.apply(lambda x: x[1].val2, axis=1)
```

The final goal is to apply thanks to a lambda function the following calculation :

(21/45)
(45/54)
(54/79)
(79/45)
...

Wihtout having to create a new column with the shifted values as suggested in [Ynjxsjmh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73163682/11167163) Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Series.shift(-1)`

```py
DF["Output"] = DF["Val2"].shift(-1)
```

Comment: So I can't use lambda function to do so ?

Comment: why would you need a lambda?

Comment: @mozway because the real goal is to calculate the following formula : 

(21/45)
(45/54)
etc..

without having to create  a new column.

Comment: then provide a complete example, you don't need a new column (and even if you did this would still be better than apply)

Comment: @TourEiffel You can use `DF["Val2"].div(DF["Val2"].shift(-1))`

Comment: @TourEiffel If your index is like 0,1,2, you can try `df.apply(lambda row: df['Val2'].iloc[row.name+1], axis=1)` but you need to special handle the integer out of bounds.